# How to convert a coroutine to a list in Python?

Tags: python, aiohttp

I use the aiohttp library, I receive data from the server in json format. Of all the data, I need only two fields that need to be displayed in a list. But when the function is called, the coroutine is returned. How do I get the list back?

```
async def request_geocoder_api(city):
url = f"https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?city={city}&format=json"

async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
    async with session.get(url) as response:
        response_json = await response.json
        latitude = response_json[0]['lat']
        longitude = response_json[0]['lon']
return [latitude, longitude]
```

Function call:

```
answer_list = await request_geocoder_api(answer)
```

Error:

```
TypeError: object method can't be used in 'await' expression
```

Comment: I would guess you need to `await` the result of calling the coroutine.

Comment: If I call a function with await, then I get a TypeError

Comment: Please can you add the code calling your function to the question, and also any error messages you get.

Comment: @Kostik you get the TypeError because you are not calling `response.json`, you are trying to await the method and you should be awaiting the coroutine returned when you call it

Comment: That is, the coroutine is not converted to a list until all calls to this function in the code are executed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the awaitable coroutine, call the `json()` function. You are missing the `()` and just getting the function "pointer".

```
    response_json = await response.json()
```

Comment: Thanks! Now everything works. Somehow I missed this moment.